# Javascript Create-Account Not Linking To Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have set up a sign-up form in the `index.html` file and connected it to `index.js`, so that when a user types in their email and password in the respective boxes and clicks the 'Submit' button, it will add their details to a database.

However, nothing is added to the database, and no errors are given in the console. The 'firebase-database' has been included within the `html` `head` tag.

Here is the HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hobbyist</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.1/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/3.1.1/firebaseui.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/3.1.1/firebaseui.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="sign-up">
    <h2>SIGN UP</h2>
    <form action="index.html" method="post">
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email..." id="create-email"><p />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password..." id="create-password"><p />

      <button class="button" id="create-account">CREATE ACCOUNT</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the JavaScript file:

```
    (function() {
      // the config details have been removed for security reasons
      var config = {
      apiKey: "---",
      authDomain: "---",
      databaseURL: "---",
      projectId: "---",
      storageBucket: "---",
      messagingSenderId: "---"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    $(document).ready(() => {
      $('#create-account').click(() => {
        var email = document.getElementById('create-email').value;
        var password = document.getElementById('create-password').value;

        var db = firebase.database();

        db.ref('users/' + email).set({
          email: email,
          password: password
        });
      });
    });

 }());
```

I have searched and searched for a way of adding information to the database, but haven't found anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should be doing this via an API otherwise you are displaying your config data. A huge security issue.

Comment: Yeah - I am going to secure it later on, thanks :) Do you have any ideas on how to get the database working?

Answer (score 1):

We need to see the HTML here and also some form of error to report on.  The click event being captured could be off. the fact that there is nothing in the console is something to check because there is something currently within the Firebase SDK that says that it would be deprecated. I will also make a suggestion to just have the user posted to a users ref vs. the one you have above. The document store capabilities of Firebase will help with what I think you are trying to accomplish here.

```
var db = firebase.database()
db.ref("/users").set({
  email: email,
  password: password
});
```

The other thing I would check out here is `.push()` method for firebase. The `set()` method will overwrite whatever user is within the database.

Bottom line, there are questions here that need to be answered to make an accurate solution.

Comment: When I use the form in the site when hosted by Firebase, it gives the error `Uncaught Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "users/example@example.com". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"`. I have also updated the original post to include the index.html` file.

Comment: Yes, if you use your current method it will be posting to a reference that has not been created. You need to use ```db.ref("/users")``` as suggested above, because this will allow you to post to a users reference. The current way you have it set up it is referring to 1.) Something that does not exist and 2.)```example@example.com``` is not an identification of an object within your DB, so it will not find it in general. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference

Comment: I tried this, but it still doesn't add anything to the `Realtime Database` (I have tried it with `.push()` and `.set()`). Also, what is the 'document store' ability?